# ASP.NET MVC Controller causing page reload when uploading a Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

When I send a Blob to a controller via ajax, saving the file in the controller causes a page refresh. If I don't save the file, it doesn't refresh. My code:

**Update** I spun up a new blank ASP.NET MVC 5 app, copied over the ajax code, and it still refreshes the page if I save file in controller.

controller:

```
public class PicUploadTestsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult StackOverflowSample()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string UploadPic()
    {
        var length = Request.ContentLength;
        var bytes = new byte[length];
        Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, length);

        WebImage webImage = new WebImage(bytes);
        var path = Path.Combine(Globals_mt.Instance.ServerRootPath, "Areas/SampleTests/Img/test.jpg");

        //If I comment out the save, no reload happens
        webImage.Save(path);

        return "/Areas/SampleTests/Img/test.jpg";
    }
}
```

typescript:

```
$(function () {

$('#blob-upload').change((e) => {

    var input = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
    var file = input.files[0];

    getBlob(file, (blob: Blob) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', '/SampleTests/PicUploadTests/UploadPic', true);
        xhr.send(blob);
    });
});


function getBlob(file: File, callback: Function) {
    var filereader = new FileReader();

    filereader.onloadend = () => {
        var imageEl = new Image();
        imageEl.onload = () => {
            var width = imageEl.width;
            var height = imageEl.height;
            var canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
            var context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
            canvasEl.width = width;
            canvasEl.height = height;
            context.drawImage(imageEl, 0, 0, width, height);

            var blob: Blob = dataUrlToBlob(canvasEl.toDataURL(file.type));
            callback(blob);
        };
        var result = filereader.result;
        imageEl.src = result;
    };

    filereader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function dataUrlToBlob(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
        var parts = dataURL.split(',');
        var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        var raw = parts[1];

        return new Blob([raw], { type: contentType });
    }

    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;

    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
}

});
```

razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>ajax blob to FileReceiver()</label>
    <input type="file" id="blob-upload" />
}
```

This happens no matter what I've tried, including uploading the file directly, saving either the file or Blob using `file.SaveAs()`, wrapping the blob in `FormData()`, moving the save operation out of the controller to a class library, not having a form in the view, i.e. just having an `<input type="file" />` directly on the page, etc etc.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, Visual Studio 2015

Am I missing something simple here? I had this working properly once upon a time.

Note: The reason I'm uploading a blob is because in the real code, I'm sizing the image down to a thumbnail so that I don't have to upload a 6mb file to create a 75 x proportionalHeight image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with Mads Kristenson's Browser Link extension for Visual Studio, I disabled that and the issue was resolved

Comment: Thanx a lot. I had a similar issue with copying some files causing the initiating POST action to be cancelled and firing a refresh of the initial GET request :/ After disabling Browser Extension Link the issue had gone fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false from your JavaScript so that the page doesn't refresh.

```
$('#blob-upload').change((e) => {

    var input = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
    var file = input.files[0];

    getBlob(file, (blob: Blob) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', '/SampleTests/PicUploadTests/UploadPic', true);
        xhr.send(blob);
    });
return false;
});
```

Comment: It's such a small change, but i added an explanation per your suggestion

Comment: @Fran Doesn't work, page still reloads. I tried adding `return false;` everywhere I could think, nothing worked